# Prevent multiple button click when one is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, flask, jinja2

So I'm try to create an edit form when an icon is clicked, so far everything works but when one icon (edit icon) is clicked others are clicked which in turn shows the form for all.
I'm passing data to my html file through flask.

```
<!-- Form Elements -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 mb-5" >
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-center">
                    <h3 class="h6 text-uppercase mb-0"> TESTING</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="h6 mb-0">
                      {% block content %}
                        {% for complaint in value['result'] %}
                          <article class="post">
                            <header>
                                <!-- Delete icon -->
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="{{ url_for('delete', _id=complaint.id) }}">
                                        <ion-icon style="color:blue"; name="trash-sharp"></ion-icon>

                                    </a>
                                </div>
```

This is where everything happens.

```
                                <!-- Edit icon -->
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button class="py" type="button">
                                        <ion-icon size="large" name="create"></ion-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <form style="display:none"; method="POST" class="p-3" id="py1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg" id="title" placeholder="Joe Smith">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control rounded-lg" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">       
                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

You can see where the data is passed.

This is my jQuery file, it's a little rough.
I've tried a loop of some ranging from looping to binding (i know it deprecated) it just doesn't work.

```
//    $("button.py").each(function(){
//        $(this).bind('click', function(){
//            $("form.p-3").each(function(){
//                $(this).toggle();
//            });
//        });
//    });
//});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.py").on("click each", "form.p-3", function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

I'm also showing comments so you can see most of what i have done.
I'm fairly new to web programming also asking questions on stack overflow.
Also on a deadline.
Picture: https://ibb.co/0Vq8jtp

**Edit: Button and the form are created dynamically**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are looping through complaints we need a unique identifier to associate each button & form pair

```
 <!-- Edit icon -->
 <div class="text-center">
   <button class="py" type="button" data-id="{{ complaint.id }}" data-select="form-button">
     <ion-icon size="large" name="create"></ion-icon>
   </button>
 </div>

<form data-id="{{ complaint.id }}" data-select="form" style="display:none"; method="POST" class="p-3" id="py1">
    <!-- form elements ... ... ... -->
</form>
```

I am using data attribute for query selection you can even use class for that

JQuery code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('button[data-select="form-button"]').each(function () {
    let buttonId = $(this).data('id')
    $(this).bind('click', function () {
      $(`form[data-select="form"][data-id="${buttonId}"]`).toggle();
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Surprisingly this those it. You saved me day's

Answer (score 0):

Keep form class name to different if you have multiple forms.

Below code worked! Please give a try.

HTML code

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="py" type="button">
        <ion-icon size="large" name="create"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<form style="display:none" ; method="POST" class="p-3" id="py1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg" id="title" placeholder="Joe Smith">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control rounded-lg" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    
</form>
```

JQuery code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button.py").click(function () {
            console.log("button is clicked");
            $("form.p-3").toggle('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can't see any change in HTML code. I know when the button is clicked (i clicked it) but clicking one button automatically clicks the others. If you are familiar with flask/jinja you we see the page depends on what flask gives it.

Comment: Do all Other buttons open the other forms? If yes, then please check if you are keeping the class name of all forms same..

Comment: Yes they are same (probably because I'm using bootstrap). Will upload a pic soon

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue and found if all your forms have same class name and you click one icon then all the forms will be shown/opened. And, thats where it seems as if one button click invoking other buttons. But try changing form class name in HtML

Comment: Will do, i added image for reference

Comment: Changed them but problem persists